# Bayesian probability that I am a redneck (divining probability given multiple conditions)

Tags: probability

I'm fuzzy for how to apply Bayes' formula for multiple conditions.  It could be really helpful to have a concrete example worked out.  Additionally, I've always been curious if I am a redneck.  Perhaps this is an opportunity to both understand Bayesian math as well as get a finer estimate of my redneck probability?  Let's say....

The total population is 1000 people with 100 (10%) people being rednecks.

Regarding the witticisms of Jeff Foxworthy:

- 150 (15%) of the total population enjoys his comedy
- 30 (30%) rednecks think he's funny

Regarding the music of Lynyrd Skynyrd:

- 200 (20%) of the total population like their music
- 40 (40%) rednecks like their music

If I like both Jeff Foxworthy and Skynyrd, what is the probability that I am a redneck?

When explaining, please keep in mind that I am new to Bayesian probability, so if you use a term ("posterior", "classifier", etc.) that it is clear from the context to a novice what these terms denote.

**EDIT**: The example figures have been updated to have total amounts in addition to percentages.

Comment: This isn't answerable, since you don't know the correlation between liking Jeff Foxworthy and Lynyrd Skynyrd,

Comment: @Paul what do you mean by correlation?  Could you give an example?

Comment: Mathematical answer: Your apriori odds of being a redneck are $1:9$. You need likelihood ratio: $\frac{P(F,S|redneck)}{P(F,S|non-redneck)}$. Assuming independence of liking $F$ and $S$ for both rednecks and non-rednecks, you get $odds(redneck|F,S)=\frac 1 9\frac {30} {15}\frac {40} {20}=4:9$. Non-mathematical answer: if you need Bayesian statistics to decide if *you* are a redneck *yourself*, you are not self-aware enough to use Bayesian stats.